# Why is win32 API non-portable?

Tags: c++, c

I know that win32 API is written in C language and also why Qt is portable?

Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: Because Win32 API, as the name suggests is targeted fo Windows. While Qt is by design requirement is portable.

Comment: Win32 api is specific to the windows operating system which is different from other operating systems.

Comment: There is `wine` which has a goal to implement the  winapi usage on non windows systems. https://www.winehq.org/

Comment: Guess what QT on Windows calls to do the native screen drawing.

Answer (score 6):

Because WinAPI was not designed to be portable as it targets only the Windows OS while the QT framework targets multiple OS-es. The fact that WinAPI was written in C does not make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

The windows API is portable in the sense of being processor agnostic (indeed, it has run on many non-Intel processors over the years). It is not portable in the sense of being OS agnostic; although even there Microsoft's is not the only implementation of the API. The wine project has done a credible job of re-implementing the API for other platforms, to the point that windows binaries will run, at least on processors that match the binary.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the WinAPI is aimed at C makes no difference.

Just because the language is cross platform it does not mean the library (especially in the case of those like WinAPI which are *not* in the standard library) are the same.

It's just a library that interacts with the video card/processor to make a GUI on a **very** low level.  At this point it is so low level the process depends more on memory locations or processor specific operations.  IE saying that certain memory locations (specific to the OS) will reference a pixel on a screen ect.

The Win32API has been built so that it *only* "knows" the tasks for computers with Windows OS, libraries like QT, once again are still not truly "cross-platform" they have just been built to include all the relevant operations needed for each OS it covers.

Answer (score 0):

Why is a rather open question; but here's my take on it:

Win32 API is produced by microsoft; which has commercial reasons for not being portable.

QT is open source; which was created with the sole intention to be portable.

Bonus:
X11 is open source; which was created with the idea that the machine displaying the images might not be the machine running the program that wants the window.  Which makes it inherently non-portable to other APIs that don't (eg windows)

Comment: http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/